# How to mock recaptcha-container with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, recaptcha, enzyme

I've been writing some unit tests for my React application which uses phone number authentication with Firebase. I use enzyme to write the tests.

My application contains a form and a recaptcha-container inside the form. When I `shallow` my component, I have no issues (this must be because shallow function does not render the child components). However, when I use `mount`, I see the following error message on my test spec:

```
reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!
```

```
<form className="formClass" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input .../>
   <input type="submit" .../>
   <InfoLine isError={error} text={infoText} />
   <div id="recaptcha-container" />
</form>
```

And here is my mount request in my test file:

```jsx
const fakeHistory = createMemoryHistory("/");
let wrapper = mount(<PhoneNumber history={fakeHistory} />);
```

Can someone please explain how I should mount this form in enzyme?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what in your test context is even rendering anything into that `div`?

Comment: I may not give a reproducible example, but the recaptcha-container renders the recaptcha badge (grecaptcha-badge).

Comment: Then you may not get an answer. That div doesn't render anything, it's a *target* for something else.